# How to set an appointment using Exchange Server 2007 and ASP.NET, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, exchange-server-2007

Hi and thanks in advance for your help in this.

I have a need to set an appointment on someone's calendar in Exchange Server 2007 from an ASP.Net C# application. I've done some research on this but the only references I've seen are for Exchange Server 2010 and that won't work here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?!

Steve

Comment: spend more than 5 minutes looking? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb409286%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I spent more than "5 minutes looking"! You think I just gave it a "glance" then asked?! Sounds like you have a perception problem!

Comment: is the link what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes it's a good start! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  [Sending Appointments to an Outlook 2007 Calendar from an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb655909%28v=office.12%29.aspx)